# Returning anonymous types with Web API

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, json.net

When using MVC, returning adhoc Json was easy.

```
return Json(new { Message = "Hello"});
```

I'm looking for this functionality with the new Web API.

```
public HttpResponseMessage<object> Test()
{    
   return new HttpResponseMessage<object>(new { Message = "Hello" }, HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

This throws an exception as the `DataContractJsonSerializer` can't handle anonymous types.

I have replaced this with this [JsonNetFormatter](https://github.com/WebApiContrib/WebAPIContrib/blob/master/src/WebApiContrib.Formatting.JsonNet/JsonNetFormatter.cs) based on *Json.Net*.
This works if I use

```
 public object Test()
 {
    return new { Message = "Hello" };
 }
```

but I don't see the point of using Web API if I'm not returning `HttpResponseMessage`, I would be better off sticking with vanilla MVC. If I try and use:

```
public HttpResponseMessage<object> Test()
{
   return new HttpResponseMessage<object>(new { Message = "Hello" }, HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

It serializes the whole `HttpResponseMessage`.

Can anyone guide me to a solution where I can return anonymous types within a `HttpResponseMessage`?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

This doesn't work in the Beta release, but it does in the latest bits (built from http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com), so it will likely be the way for RC. You can do

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    return this.Request.CreateResponse(
        HttpStatusCode.OK,
        new { Message = "Hello", Value = 123 });
}
```

Comment: An important note, Only the default json serializer can handle serialization of anonymous objects. The default xml serializer will error out so be sure if you return anonymous objects that your clients know to send accept:application/json in header. Browser's like Chrome tend to request xml by default as well so just a heads up..

Answer (score 24):

This answer may come bit late but as of today `WebApi 2` is already out and now it is easier to do what you want, you would just have to do:

```
public object Message()
{
    return new { Message = "hello" };
}
```

and along the pipeline, it will be serialized to `xml` or `json` according to client's preferences (the `Accept` header). Hope this helps anyone stumbling upon this question

Comment: @doker What version of WebApi are you using, I just pasted that code from my controller using VS 2015 and WebApi2

Comment: 5.2.3 and I ended up removing xml formater because most returned objects wouldn't serialize to xml anyway.

Comment: @doker in your case then when you try to do what I suggested what happens? do you get an `Exception`?

Answer (score 12):

In web API 2 you can use the new IHttpActionResult which is a replacement for HttpResponseMessage and then return a simple Json object: (Similiar to MVC)

```
public IHttpActionResult GetJson()
    {
       return Json(new { Message = "Hello"});
    }
```

Comment: Best answer for me. I need a way to return slim JSON from Web API Action without producing additional stuff in different places / assemblies. Works like a charm! Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

you can use JsonObject for this:

```
dynamic json = new JsonObject();
json.Message = "Hello";
json.Value = 123;

return new HttpResponseMessage<JsonObject>(json);
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use an [ExpandoObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). *(add `using System.Dynamic;`)*

```
[Route("api/message")]
[HttpGet]
public object Message()
{
    dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
    expando.message = "Hello";
    expando.message2 = "World";
    return expando;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You may also try:

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://leojh.com");
var requestModel = new {User = "User", Password = "Password"};
request.Content = new ObjectContent(typeof(object), requestModel, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
```

Answer (score 3):

In ASP.NET Web API 2.1 you can do it in a simpler way:

```
public dynamic Get(int id) 
{
     return new 
     { 
         Id = id,
         Name = "X"
     };
}
```

You can read more about this on https://www.strathweb.com/2014/02/dynamic-action-return-web-api-2-1/

Answer (score 3):

```
public IEnumerable<object> GetList()
{
    using (var context = new  DBContext())
    {
        return context.SPersonal.Select(m =>
            new  
            {
                FirstName= m.FirstName ,
                LastName = m.LastName
            }).Take(5).ToList();               
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to get this to work if you use generics, as it will give you a "type" for your anonymous type. You can then bind the serializer to that.

```
public HttpResponseMessage<T> MakeResponse(T object, HttpStatusCode code)
{
    return new HttpResponseMessage<T>(object, code);
}
```

If there are no `DataContract` or `DataMebmer` attributes on your class, it will fall back on serializing all public properties, which should do exactly what you're looking for.

(I won't have a chance to test this until later today, let me know if something doesn't work.)

Answer (score 0):

You can encapsulate dynamic object in returning object like

```
public class GenericResponse : BaseResponse
{
    public dynamic Data { get; set; }
}
```

and then in WebAPI; do something like:

```
[Route("api/MethodReturingDynamicData")]
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage MethodReturingDynamicData(RequestDTO request)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response;
    try
    {
        GenericResponse result = new GenericResponse();
        dynamic data = new ExpandoObject();
        data.Name = "Subodh";

        result.Data = data;// OR assign any dynamic data here;// 

        response = Request.CreateResponse<dynamic>(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ApplicationLogger.LogCompleteException(ex, "GetAllListMetadataForApp", "Post");
        HttpError myCustomError = new HttpError(ex.Message) { { "IsSuccess", false } };
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, myCustomError);
    }
    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET Core Web API 6 you can use OK:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetSomething()
{
    return Ok(new { Message = "Hello World" });
}
```