# Returning an anonymous type from MVC 4 Web Api fails with a serialization error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm just getting started with MVC 4 Web API and I seem to be misunderstanding how it works.

Before Web API I had a simple MVC action method like this:

```
public JsonResult User()
{
    return Json(new
    {
        firstName = "Joe",
        lastName = "Jacobs",
        email = "joe.jacobs@gmail.com"
    });
}
```

That would work fine. In the new web API controller I am trying to do something similar.

```
public object User()
{
    return new
    {
        firstName = "Joe",
        lastName = "Jacobs",
        email = "joe.jacobs@gmail.com"
    }
}
```

This fails with a serialization error:

> The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'.

Inner exception:

> Type '<>f__AnonymousType1`3[System.String,System.String,System.String]' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute. If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute. See the Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for other supported types.

What am I not understanding about returning anonymous type from the API controller?

Comment: Have you tried and checked if it works when you request json rather than xml? Anyway, look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123371/returning-anonymous-types-with-web-api, you can use `HttpResponseMessage` as the return type for your WebApi method and add the resource to it.

Comment: "I'm hitting the URL in my browser so I do understand that by default it will try to return XML, but I get the same error even if I request JSON."

Comment: What is your browser? Chrome?

Comment: Yes. It fails regardless of browser.

Comment: This is odd as I'm doing this right now, the same way you are. If you use JsonResult and return JSON - is it JSON you're requesting as a type in your client-side call, rather than XML?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you look at the Fiddler (sample in here I use Firefox)

[image]

By default, request from browser will *accepts* application/xml, not  application/json

But, you can create *fake request* from Fiddler by adding one header:

```
Accept: application/json
```

It will work

From the [link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization#json_anon):

> The XML serializer does not support anonymous types or JObject instances. If you use these features for your JSON data, you should remove the XML formatter from the pipeline, as described later in this article.

How to remove `XmlFormatter`:

```
  var configuration = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
  configuration.Formatters.Remove(configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also use the JsonMediaTypeFormatter so you do not need the JSONObject and related classes. Then you can return a dynamic type in your controller class.

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.Formatters.Clear();            
    config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
}

public class YourController : ApiController
{        
    [HttpGet, Route("getstuff/{stuffId}")]
    public dynamic Get(string stuffId)
    {
        var stuff = Model.Stuff.Get(stuffId);

        return new {
            success= stuff != null,
            stuffId = stuff.Id,
            name = stuff.Name
        };
    }
}
```

If you also want to support Jsonp you can inherit the JsonMediaTypeFormatter and create you own JsonpMediaTypeFormatter (which also can be found on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12492552/1138266).

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem and the solution was to add a snippet to the 
`Global.asax.cs` file.

The snippet to add is as follows:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings
            .ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters
            .Remove(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

I also added the above lines of code to the very top of the Application_Start method which left the method looking like this:

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings
            .ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters
            .Remove(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the API didn't like returning a raw list.  Instead, I had to create an object, and set the value of the object as my list; see the first return statement.

Example:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetMessages(int messageFeedId, int lastMessageId) {
    List<Message> messageDomainObjects = MessageService.GetMessages(messageFeedId, lastMessageId);

    if (messageDomainObjects.Any())
    {
        var messages = messageDomainObjects.Select(m => new MessageModel(
            m.Id,
            m.Message,
            m.CreatedDate,
            m.IsActive,
            new UserModel(
                m.User.Id,
                m.User.FirstName,
                m.User.LastName
            )
        ));

        return Ok(new { messages = messages });
    }
    else
    {
        return Ok(new { });
    }
}
```