# The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json'

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, appharbor

I am using asp.net MVC with WebApi. Everything is working fine on localhost but on appharbor deployed website i am getting exception `The 'ObjectContent 1 type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'` on each call to webapi controller.

My webapi function is:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetMobileTrends()
        {
            var ret = (from ad in db.MobileAds
                      orderby ad.Ad.views
                      where ad.Ad.AdImages.Count > 0
                      select new
                      {
                          title = ad.Ad.title,
                          id = ad.Ad.Id,
                          //other attributes
                      });
            return Ok(ret);
        }
```

To tackle this exception I added two lines to `Application_Start` function in  `Global.asax.cs` :

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Remove(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
        }
```

But it didn't work. Then I added following lines at end of `Register` function in `WebApiConfig.cs` :

```
var json = configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
configuration.Formatters.Remove(configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

It still didn't work. I don't want to create a model as I am using knockout. Also if I create model for each webapi call. There are going to be 30 to 40 models (data retrieved in each call is different).

> Is there a way to tackle this exception without creating a model?

**Update:**
My question is not duplicate. 
My ajax function is:

```
self.loadad = function () {
                url_address = '/api/Electronic/GetMobileTrends';
                $.ajax({
                    url: url_address,
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    cache: false,
                    type: 'GET',
                    success: function (data) {
                        var mappedads = $.map(data, function (item) { return new ad(item); });
                        self.showAds(mappedads);

                    },
                    error: function () {
                        toastr.error("Unable to load data. Please try again", "Error");
                    }
                });
            }
```

Comment: Any comment?? Please tell me if my question is not clear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning an anonymous type from MVC 4 Web Api fails with a serialization error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962134/returning-an-anonymous-type-from-mvc-4-web-api-fails-with-a-serialization-error)

Comment: my question is not duplicate. I am already using `application/json` (as told in answer 1) and i have tried adding the lines `config.Formatters.Clear();            
    config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();` in Register function (as told in answer 2) but it didn't work

Comment: I'm running into this issue as well. Everything is fine on localhost, but not when deployed. If it was a code or models issue, it'd happen locally too. And it's a recent issue too. I suspect something changed upstream from me, but I need some inspiration where to look.

Comment: I ran into the same problem and solved this by creating a constructor in the api controller and put  db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false; in the constructor. I have followed a comment in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641386/failed-to-serialize-the-response-in-web-api