# How to Serializable Data in Table Relationships using DataContract and DataMember, get XML Data Format

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have trouble getting the xml data format from sql database, I am getting both json and xml and using `[HttpGet("get.{format}"), FormatFilter]` to retrieve the data format if json and xml, getting xml data format is having an error saying this.

`InvalidDataContractException: Type '<>f__AnonymousType2`2[System.Int32,<>f__AnonymousType3`1[System.String][]]' cannot be serialized....`

This is my Table 1 :

```
[DataContract]
public class Table1
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Table1Id { get; set; }
    public int Table2Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual Table2 Table2 { get; set; }
}
```

This is my Table 2 :

```
[DataContract]
public class Table2 
{
    public Table2 ()
    {
        Table1 = new HashSet<Table1>();
    }

    public int Table2Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Table1> Table1 { get; set; }
}
```

This is my Linq Query :

```
var navpoint = await _context.Table1
                   .Include(c => c.Table2)
                   .Select(c => new
                   {
                       Table1Id = c.Table1Id,
                       Table2 = new[] {
                            new {
                                Name = c.Table2.Name 
                            }
                       }
                   })
                   .ToListAsync();
```

Can someone help me with this problem, please...

Comment: According to the error you provided, you are returning collection of anonymous type instead of your actual type defined as attribute which can be the culprit for this error, check with `new{} `keyword in your code. And you also can try the method used in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962134/returning-an-anonymous-type-from-mvc-4-web-api-fails-with-a-serialization-error) ,creating fake request from Fiddler by adding one header.

Comment: Can you tell me what does table1 in your database look like? What is the data in it?

Comment: I updated the query my mistake, the problem occur when you include selecting the data from the table2 @QingGuo

Comment: The problem occurs during database query, so I need to know what the table looks like in your database so that I can further analyze the cause of the problem.

Comment: okay but I don't really get what you mean by `so I need to know what the table looks like in your database`, what do you mean by that @QingGuo?

Comment: @vernou can you help me with this?

Comment: I mean could  you share the test data from your database, screenshots are also ok.

Comment: You mean the data from the tables? If that's what you meant the data's are in the classis above @QingGuo