# WebAPI producing Data with relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to create an API using WebAPI which produces parent data with child data using JSON result type.

I am able to send the data using two separate calls sending firm details and a collection of addresses (List of Addresses) but I would like to send this information in one call so currently I can do

addresss/api/firm - Firm Information

address/api/addresses - Addresses collection.

I would like to use addresss/api/firm which will include the firm information and collection of addresses together in one call.

I am not using Entity Framework.  All the examples I have seen to do this seem to be using EF.

I have a dto for Firm Information and a List of DTOAddresses for Address information.

I have spent quite a long time looking at this and getting no further.

Thanks for you help in advance.

Comment: If you give `Firm` a property of type `List<DTOAddresses>` then WebAPI will properly serialize the nesting automatically.

Comment: How would this work though as I am already returning the method as a DTO type of Firm which is actually an AutoMapper created DTO I then want to return DtoFirmAddresses as part of the GET alongside by firm DTO

Comment: As you've shown no code it is difficult to provide a solution, but you could try returning an anonymous object like `new { firm = firmVariable, addresses = addressesVariabl }` as seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123371/returning-anonymous-types-with-web-api)

Comment: Thank you so much Crowcoder,  That worked and so simple in the end.